# R: Sort a list based on values in the elements, ideally somthing chained that works with purrr/tidyverse

Tags: r, sorting, tidyverse, purrr

I'd like to arrange items in a list based on criteria, much like dplyr::arrange does for data.frames (while maintaining a chained syntax).

```
    ## Something along the lines of:

    list(
        list( foo="baz"  ),
        list( foo="test" ),
        list( foo="bar"  )
    ) %>% arrange( foo )

    ## .. would result in a structure equivalent of:
    list(
        list( foo="bar"  ),
        list( foo="baz"  ),
        list( foo="test" )
    )
```

I would expect something like this existed, but weren't able to find it

EDIT: I removed the variable 'l' for clarity

EDIT2: Can't change to a tibble along the path, to use dplyr::arrange, as elements might not support that, or they might not have matching names

Answer (score 2):

You could `unlist`, `sort` and put it back in same structure using `relist`.

```
relist(sort(unlist(l)), l)

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$foo
#[1] "bar"


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$foo
#[1] "baz"


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$foo
#[1] "test"
```

Comment: I could also fetch the $foo , order that, and reorder based on that index.
However I need to be able to chain this with other tidyverse method calls

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What is the issue in the current method? If you want to use pipes you can do `l %>% unlist %>% sort %>% relist(l)`

Comment: yes, like that, only without having an 'l' in the first place. I could have made that clearer. I will have an arbitrary length chain of method calls, that I want to rearrange at some point. I'm asking if there's a tidyverse way of doing that. This implies you don't stop to save it, and then rearrange.

Comment: Sure, for this example, but not for the general approach, as it changes data to a tibble before chaning back

Comment: So you don't want to convert to tibble for sorting? Can you include all the restrictions in your original post so that it is clear for people who are answering.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not aware of any tidyverse function for such sorting, but you can try this:

```
list(
  list( foo="baz"  ),
  list( foo="test" ),
  list( foo="bar"  )) %>% 
  `[`(order(map_chr(.,~pluck(.x,"foo"))))
```